# Ubuntu 22.04 Autoinstall method

Tags: boot, grub2, iso, cloud-init, autoinstall

Does anybody figured out the right way of providing autoinstall data with custom iso file via grub?
Clearly Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't provide the nice way of definition of boot commands via casper (sort of interactive menu [after boot, F6 and so on..]) like Ubuntu 20.04 does.

Starting point:

- Ubuntu 22.04 iso file downloaded from Ubuntu site.
- custom iso file with user-data and meta-data

Custom iso contains:

- user-data with 'answers' for installer
- meta-data is an empty file

Iso file is created by this command:
`mkisofs -V cidata -lJR -o custom.iso user-data meta-data`

So the mark 'cidata' (necessary as cloud-init documentation describes) is present.
Now once the vm is created and started installer simply fails to find answer file and it starts with the installer guide instead. However user-data can be found in this path:

```
/var/lib/cloud/instances/nocloud/user-data.txt
```

This file contains the original data I've created.

Now the most important part is the GRUB, that looks like:

```
       `linux /casper/vmlinuz autoinstall quiet \"ds=nocloud;s=/\" ---
        initrd /casper/initrd
        boot`
```

This example should be just fine, however it is not. Even if I provide full path to the file - it is a no go. I also tried to provide answer files via http server, but result is the same.

That example:

```
       `linux /casper/vmlinuz autoinstall quiet ---
        initrd /casper/initrd
        boot`
```

Should be enough as well but it doesn't work either.
Any ideas, anyone?

**EDIT 26.5.2022**
Found some working piece at least with http server. So working boot command is:

```
       `linux /casper/vmlinuz --- autoinstall quiet 'ds=nocloud-net;s=http://192.168.100.100/'
        initrd /casper/initrd
        boot`
```

Now further info about additional iso file. I think it's not being mounted properly. Since with this command:

```
       `linux /casper/vmlinuz --- autoinstall quiet
        initrd /casper/initrd
        boot`
```

I see a user-data.txt file in this path:

```
/var/lib/cloud/instances/nocloud/user-data.txt
```

That is fine, some logs however show:

`cat /var/log/cloud-init-output.log Cloud-init v. 22.1-14-g2e17a0d6-0ubuntu1~22.04.5 finished at Thu, 26 May 2022 10:52:10 +0000. Datasource DataSourceNoCloudNet [seed=cmdline,/var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud,/dev/sr1][dsmode=net].  Up 63.17 seconds`

`cat /var/log/cloud-init.log 2022-05-26 10:51:24,065 - subp.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['mount', '-o', 'ro', '-t', 'auto', '/dev/sr1', '/run/cloud-init/tmp/tmpb4d62dyf'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True) 2022-05-26 10:51:35,825 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: finish: init-network/consume-user-data: SUCCESS: reading and applying user-data`

So clearly something happens there. Nonetheless with boot commands listed above **NO** files are being downloaded from the addional iso file. Meaning that file: */var/lib/cloud/instances/nocloud/user-data.txt* is EMPTY. If I do manually *mount /dev/sr1 /mnt* I can see my user-data.

Perhaps somehow mount the iso file with the GRUB cli and pointing the cloud-init to that? Certainly an option..
Will keep hacking..

Comment: Because you see the `user-data` file at `/var/lib/cloud/instances/nocloud/user-data.txt` I would suspect that your `user-data` file is being rejected for having an error.  There might be a clue in `/var/log/cloud-init*` or `/var/log/installer/*`, but the logs usually are not clear about why a `user-data` file is ignored.  You can share the entire `user-data` file if you are comfortable doing so.

Comment: Sure, check it out: https://pastebin.com/YU6SPDwh. This worked with Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: It doesn't work even with the minimal config here: https://pastebin.com/rfcE2dyz. Despite the facts that the file is visiable at: /var/lib/cloud/instances/nocloud/user-data.txt

Comment: Is there any way how can I 're-run'the installer? Meaning change the console, kill the default installer and start it again with an argument of the path with user-data?

Comment: Neither file you uploaded begins with the line `#cloud-config`.  This line is not optional.  Omitting this line will lead to the behavior you describe.

Comment: An alternative to autoinstall is to install an **Ubuntu preinstalled image** of an already installed system, that can boot both in UEFI mode and BIOS mode (alias CSM alias legacy mode). We can find such images also for PC computers with 'amd64' architecture now. They can be managed like images for Raspberry Pi, by extraction and cloning to the target drive. Read more about it at [this link to a thread at the Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474692).

Comment: For anyone else not that familiar with GRUB, ... the single-quotes around the argument is needed for the 
'ds=nocloud-net;s=http://192.168.100.100/'

or, alternatively, without quotes ...  
ds=nocloud-net\;s=http://192.168.100.100/     (note the backslash before the semicolon)

Knowing that in advance would have saved me several hours on this task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a while the problem is solved.
The correct boot command is:

```
   `linux /casper/vmlinuz autoinstall quiet ---
    initrd /casper/initrd
    boot`
```

and installer looks for *user-data* file indeed automatically. Do not really understand why providing 'ds=' section brakes it entirely. All you need is to generate iso file with *cidata* label containing at least two common files the *user-data* and *meta-data*. Also the content of *user-file* differs from what we have been using in Ubuntu 20.04, some bugs are gone which is good. As of today (26.5.2022) the Ubuntu [autoinstall](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall) docs is sufficient so as the [cloud-init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) doc.

Thanks Andrew Lowther for good point.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
menuentry "Try or Install Ubuntu Server" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz autoinstall quiet ds='nocloud;s=/cdrom/' ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd
}
```

When user-data and meta-data in root dir of iso.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Result is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with packer on vSphere. you can check the tutorial (link below) where he used Packer's `cd_files` to create a temporary ISO file containing the cloud-config files and mount it as an additional CD drive.
N.B: in the tutorial, you will find ubuntu 20.04, but it works just fine if you change the iso path to your ubuntu 22.04 instance.
https://tekanaid.com/posts/hashicorp-packer-build-ubuntu20-04-vmware

Comment: Did you try it? I don't think it works since the guide uses: `boot_command = [
    "<esc><wait>",` but this part GRUB doesn't eat... So you can't simply change iso file.. In got it working, do you mind to share your boot command?

Answer (score 0):

```
set timeout=-1
menuentry "Install Ubuntu Server 22 " {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz quiet autoinstall ds=nocloud\;s=/cdrom/nocloud/ ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd
}
```

On the thumbdrive there is in the root a dir "nocloud" with a modified 'user-data' file.

Comment: No, this doesn't work either. The custom data are available at: /var/lib/cloud/instances/nocloud/ but even with that path it doesn't work. Besides that official documentation is still silet :/

Answer (score 0):

The layout from the root from the thumbdrive looks like this:

```
.disk
boot
casper
dists
EFI
install
nocloud
pool
autorun.ico
autorun.inf
boot.catalog
md5sum.txt
```

I made my thumbdrive with the original ISO Ubuntu 22.04 and written with Rufus.
The thumbdrive is used to install servers unattended. I used this earlier for Ubuntu 20.04, before that I was using kickseed and d-i answers

Comment: Yeah, but in this case you have to regenerate the entire iso file everytime you want to change something, right? I just do not understand what has actually changed in 22.04, as I've mentioned Ubuntu documentation is old now since it provides a guide for Ubuntu 20.04 and clearly something t has changed..

Comment: Perhaps this is the solution for you: https://www.molnar-peter.hu/en/ubuntu-jammy-netinstall-pxe.html

Comment: Hey, I've seen this as page as well, problem is that new Ubuntu ignores either web or file path, as I've described in the initial description ..

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone looking for HTTP autoinstall on 22.04 vs 20.04.

This is used in a Hashicorp Packer build but these are the same commands you would run on the CLI anyway.

**GRUB -> 20.04**:

```yaml
boot_command    = [
                     "<wait>",
                     "<esc><esc><esc>",
                     "<enter><wait>",
                     "/casper/vmlinuz ",
                     "initrd=/casper/initrd ",
                     "ip=${var.vm_nic1_ip_address}::${var.vm_nic1_ip_gateway}:${var.vm_nic1_ip_netmask}:${var.vm_name}:::${var.vm_nic1_nameservers[0]}:${var.vm_nic1_nameservers[1]} ",
                     "autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;s=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/${local.ai_target_dir} ",
                     "boot",
                     "<enter><wait>"
                    ]
```

i.e

1. Boot ISO
2. Press `<esc>` key 3 times
3. Prompt to exit from GUI interactive: Press  to confirm 'yes'
4. Type `/casper/vmlinuz initrd=/casper/initrd ip=192.168.0.1::192.168.0.254:255.255.255.0:testdeploysrv01.local.com:::8.8.8.8:8.4.4.4 autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;s=http://192.168.0.250:9090/testdeploysrv01.local.com boot`
5. Press `<enter>`

- 192.168.0.1 = temp IP to assign the booting server (if you don't have DHCP)
- 192.168.0.354 = IP gateway for this subnet
- 255.255.255.0 = subnet mask
- testdeploysrv01.local.com = FQDN of the booting server
- 8.8.8.8 = DNS 1
- 8.4.4.4 = DNS 2

**GRUB -> 22.04**:

```yaml
locals {

  ## Autoinstall targets
    ## ai = autoinstall
  ai_target_dir      = "${var.vm_name}/"
  ai_data_source     = "ds=\"nocloud-net;seedfrom=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/${local.ai_target_dir}\""
  ai_boot_ip_addr    = "ip=${var.vm_nic1_ip_address}::${var.vm_nic1_ip_gateway}:${var.vm_nic1_ip_netmask}:${var.vm_name}:::${var.vm_nic1_nameservers[0]}:${var.vm_nic1_nameservers[1]}"
}

boot_command    = [
                    "<wait>",
                    "c",
                    "<wait>",
                    "linux /casper/vmlinuz autoinstall --- ${local.ai_boot_ip_addr} ${local.ai_data_source}",
                    "<enter><wait>",
                    "initrd /casper/initrd ",
                    "<enter><wait>",                     
                    "boot",
                    "<enter><wait>",
                    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

With Packer and ubuntu 22 iso file, I use this boot command and it works with the additional cdrom added by packer for autoinstall

```
vm_boot_command = [
        "<esc>c<wait>",
        "linux /casper/vmlinuz autoinstall quiet ds=nocloud ipv6.disable=1 ---",
        "<enter><wait>",
        "initrd /casper/initrd<enter><wait>",
        "boot<enter>"
]
```